# Adjusting the size of a widget

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to adjust the size of a widget on a website for my town (summer student who can actually use a computer so it falls to me). The problem is that the widget is basically the entire site but won't autosize so that there isn't a scroll bar for the widget

So I've tried changing the values from %'s to px's but don't get the results I'm looking for, it stretches the content rather than the box.

```
        targetObject.style.width = "100%";
        targetObject.style.height = "100%";
        widget.children[0].style.width = "100%";
        widget.children[0].style.height = "100%";
```

So I changed the percents to px and it stretched the physical content inside the widget instead of the box and it also won't let me make the height 200%.

Comment: You may want to play around with the sizing using the web browsers inspector and see if you can get it to look how you want there, and then you can apply that to your code. It sounds like you may be modifying the wrong element which is why it's not turning out the way you want.

Comment: @ComputerLocus so it looks like the widget extends up behind the header.. I tried adding some <br> to move it down with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say since I don't have much to go by. You may have to modify other CSS on the page, not just the widgets CSS in order to resize it.

Comment: @ComputerLocus so I found an object that lets me expand it, <object type="text/html" data = "url" style = "width = 100%; height: 500px;" .. could I put the object into CSS?

Comment: Yeah for sure :).